# (Why) is $p \land \lnot(p \land \lnot q) \Leftrightarrow p \land q$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

I'm trying to understand a proof for $B \cap A = A \setminus (A \setminus B) $, with $B \subseteq A$ which goes like this:

In general: $y \in A \setminus B \Leftrightarrow y \in A \land \lnot(y \in B)$

$x \in A \setminus (A \setminus B)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in A \land \lnot(x \in A \land \lnot(x \in B))$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in A \land \lnot (x \in A) \lor \lnot\lnot(x \in B)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in A \land \lnot (x \in A) \lor (x \in B)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in A \land x \in B$

I don't understand how the last step works. In a footnote it says that $p \land \lnot(p \land \lnot q)$ is equivalent to $p \land q$.
I don't quite understand why though. Could someone explain?

Comment: Um, do you mean if $B\subset A$ then $B=A \setminus (A \setminus B)$? Because $B \subseteq A = A \setminus (A \setminus B)$ is not true.

Comment: Don't remove the parenthesis: $U\land (V\lor W)$ is different than $(U\land V)\lor W$.

Comment: Whoops, I mixed some things up, I corrected it.

Comment: Well, now it's true, but the condition $B\subseteq A$ is not required for it to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
p \land \lnot (p \land \lnot q) &= p \land (\lnot p \lor q) &\qquad \mbox{de Morgan rule}\\
&= (p \land \lnot p) \lor (p \land q) &\qquad \mbox{By distributivity}\\
&= (p \land q) &\qquad \mbox{since $x \land \lnot x = 0$ and $0 \lor x = x$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
p \land \lnot(p \land \lnot q) &\iff p \land(\lnot p \lor q) && \text{(DeMorgan's Law)}\\
&\iff (p \land \lnot p) \lor (p \land q) && \text{(Distributivity of logical conjunction)} \\
&\iff p \land q && (p \land \lnot p) \text{ is a contradiction}
\end{align*}